# mySQL group_concat max dates based on other column

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have input table:

```
+-----+------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+
| id  | client_id  | subscription_date   | program |how_long_subs|
+-----+------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+
|   1 |          1 | 2016-05-20 00:00:00 | W90     |          12 |
|   2 |          4 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | W90     |           6 |
| 314 |          7 | 2017-03-21 00:00:00 | AB      |          12 |
|   3 |          8 | 2016-12-19 00:00:00 | W90     |          12 |
|   4 |          9 | 2018-06-08 00:00:00 | W90     |          12 |
|   5 |         10 | 2017-06-12 00:00:00 | W90     |          12 |
| 313 |         10 | 2017-01-18 00:00:00 | AB      |          12 |
| 377 |         11 | 2018-12-22 00:00:00 | AB      |          12 |
| 308 |         11 | 2017-12-22 00:00:00 | AB      |          12 |
|   6 |         11 | 2017-12-22 00:00:00 | W90     |          12 |
|   7 |         13 | 2017-01-05 00:00:00 | W90     |           6 |
|   8 |         21 | 2017-03-10 00:00:00 | W90     |          12 |
| 325 |         22 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 | AB      |           1 |
+-----+------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+
```

id is unique autoincremented column for this table client_id is to connect with clients table. I am looking for a result in form:

```
+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------+--------+
| client_id  | programs |                  dates                  |how_long|
+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------+--------+
|          1 | W90      |  2016-05-20 00:00:00                    | 12     |
|        ... |          |                                         |        |
|         11 | W90|AB   | 2017-12-22 00:00:00|2018-12-22 00:00:00 | 12|12  |
+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------+--------+
```

so every client_id has 3 columns: programs, dates, how_long

so far I have below for columns programy and na_ile

```
SELECT
  client_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT program SEPARATOR '|') AS programs
FROM subscriptions GROUP BY client_id
```

but I have no idea how to do this for dates, so everything is in good order.
in example result I chose some client that has multiple rows for different programs, to best illustrate, as you can see dates in result are MAX date for certain program.

To give you better picture what I'm trying to do is process my input table, to be able to calculate remaining subscription for different programs.

Formula is:
if client_id has no records in subscriptions then use date from clients table
and return difference between that date +1 year and today.
if client_id has records in subscriptions then
for every unique program client has in subs table:
 get max subscription_date and corresponding how_long_subs for that max date/program. add how_long_subs months to subscription date and return difference from now in days.

My plan is to get result table as described above and use php to process rows to get something like this:

```
example result for client_id: 11
W90: 2017-12-22 00:00:00 +12 months - now()
AB: 2018-12-22 00:00:00 +12 months - now()
```

Can you please help me with mySQL query and advice if approach im taking is ok or maybe there is some much easier way of doing it.

Thank you

Comment: You mention php, so I'd do its there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.client_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT A.program SEPARATOR '|') programs,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT A.subscription_date SEPARATOR '|') dates,
GROUP_CONCAT(A.how_long_subs SEPARATOR '|') how_long   
FROM 
(SELECT client_id, subscription_date, MAX(program) program, how_long_subs
FROM subscriptions
GROUP BY client_id, subscription_date,how_long_subs) A
GROUP BY A.client_id;
```

See [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gvpixFRFboqXSjr9NtaMHi/0).

Comment: thank you so much!!! could you comment on my approach of calculating remaining subscription, i feel like there is much better way i just dont see it.

Comment: You should ask that as a separate questions with some sample and expected data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery for get the max date

```
SELECT client_id, GROUP_CONCAT( program SEPARATOR '|') programs, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(max_date SEPARATOR '|') max_date
FROM (
SELECT
  client_id,
  programs,
  max(subscription_date) max_date
FROM subscriptions
GROUP BY client_id, program )
```

Comment: the result i get with this is like this:
1
W90|W90|AB|W90|W90|AB|W90|AB|W90|W90|W90|AB|W90|W9...
2016-05-20 00:00:00|2017-01-01 00:00:00|2017-03-21...